# My code is returning False even if there is a vowel in a word

Tags: python

Program and problem summarised below

Python 3.7.1 version

```
def has_vowel(s):
    '''(str) -> bool
    Retrun True only if s has atleast one vowel, not including y.
    >>> has_vowel('Anniversary')
    True
    >>> has_vowel('xyz')
    False
    '''

    vowel_found = False
    for char in s:
        if char in 'aieouAIEOU':
            return not vowel_found
        else:
            return vowel_found
```

Expected results

```
>>> has_vowel('Bhoot')
True
```

Actual results

```
>>> has_vowel('Bhoot')
False
```

Comment: You're only checking the _first_ character in the string and returning after that.

Comment: `for char in s` iterate s, which means the function will return immediately with the first character of s.

Comment: `for char in s` iterate s, which means the function will return immediately with the first character of s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function iterates over every value in the string but is only checking if the the first value is a vowel because you `return` on the first iteration. You need to check if it exists anywhere:

```
def has_vowel(s):
    '''(str) -> bool
    Retrun True only if s has atleast one vowel, not including y.
    >>> has_vowel('Anniversary')
    True
    >>> has_vowel('xyz')
    False
    '''

    for char in s:
        if char in 'aieouAIEOU':
            return True
    return False
```

The `else` would make the program instantly `return` even thought it hasn't checked the rest of the string.

```
>>> has_vowel("Bhoot")
True
>>> has_vowel("xyz")
False
```